# meta.stackoverflow.com has a problem

Tags: support, openid

Sorry, this is off topic, but fact evolved that meta.stackoverflow does only allow posting with openid despite stating possibility of post per nick/email. Posted here because underlying prob stemmed from serverfault.

So here is a copy: Despite stating that submission via nick/email were possible, required fields are not given. Please fix or state that critique be only issued non anonymously.

Tags

OpenID Login

Get an OpenID
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

must include one of these tags -- bug feature-request discussion support
users with less than 99 reputation can't create new tags. The tag 'limit' is new. Try using an existing tag instead.
name and email, or your OpenID, are missing

Comment: I fail to see the problem...  But this clearly belongs on Meta

Comment: From http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq: **Do I have to log in or create an account?**  Yes. You must have a registered account on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User to participate here.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question...if there is a question.

Answer (score 2):

Eh, let me see if I can make some sense out of this:

> Your question couldn't be submitted because: [?] must include one of these tags -- bug feature-request discussion support

When posting on meta, one of your tags must be either `bug`, `feature-request`, `discussion`, or `support`. If you do not have one of these tags, it will not be accepted by the system.

> users with less than 99 reputation can't create new tags.

You must use existing tags until you have 100 reputation, which you can gain by associating your accounts.

As for OpenID, please clarify what you mean.